# Установка значения по условию Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица с данными

```
Категория   Значение
4   3
2   5
4   2
5   6
3   7
2   8
4   2
3   1
2   1
```

И таблица критериев:

```
Кат.    Средний Высокий
1   4   5
2   4   10
3   5   6
4   6   7
5   5   8
```

Нужно в первой таблице соотнести значение с таблицей. Если меньше среднего - тогда пишем `C`, если больше высокого пишем `A`, иначе - `B`

То есть на выходе нужно получить:

```
Категория   Значение    Res
4   3   C
2   5   B
4   2   C
5   6   B
3   7   A
2   8   B
4   2   C
3   1   C
2   1   C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соединим таблицы по полю "категория" и расставим результат на основе сравнения

```
df1['res'] = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='Категория', right_on='Кат.') \ 
[['Средний','Высокий']].gt(df1['Значение'].values.reshape(-1,1)).sum(axis=1) \
.map(dict(enumerate('ABC')))

df1
   Категория  Значение res
0          4         3   C
1          2         5   B
2          4         2   C
3          5         6   B
4          3         7   A
5          2         8   B
6          4         2   C
7          3         1   C
8          2         1   C
```