# Python: Необходимо добавить элемент в список подобно функции insert, не используя при этом стандартные средства языка

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, insert

Сразу же оговорюсь, что я понимаю, что змею для таких целей использовать бы не стоило, но реализовать как-то хочется. В общем, суть проблемы: необходимо в список вставить элемент по индексу подобно функции insert, при этом необходимо работать только с этим списком, не создавать новые, нельзя использовать конкатенацию или срезы, функции для работы со списками (разве, что len), в общем написать true алгоритм.

У меня была следующая идея - увеличить длину списка на один, дальше алгоритм написать алгоритм будет просто. НО, как это сделать без добавления в него элемента функцией append, я не нашёл.

Ещё одна идея - как-то увеличить объём выделяемой памяти для списка (метод **sizeof**) на объём занимаемой памяти добавляемым элементом. Но и тут провал в поисках решения.

Кода никакого нет, потому что самое начало этого алгоритма (видимо) и является проблемой. Надеюсь: у вас будут предложения.

Comment: Вот тут есть пример https://dbader.org/blog/python-linked-list

Comment: @becouse Не могли бы Вы немного раскрыть мысль? На что именно стоит обратить внимание в статье про связные списки, чтобы решить задачу автора?

Comment: В статье пример реализации связанного списка на Питоне. Собственно начиная со слов "A Singly-Linked List Class in Python".

Comment: Вы решаете какую-то практическую задачу, или это просто упражнение на знание питона?

Comment: Какими методами/функциями (кроме `len()`) можно пользоваться? Можно ли использовать оператор индексации по списку: `list[index]`? Можно ли использовать метод `.append()`?

Comment: @becouse, идея со связным списком, состоящим из элементов списка может сработать если можно использовать оператор / метод для доступа к элементам списка по индексу иначе придется создавать новый список...

Comment: @Xander это и является задачей, но она включает вот эти ограничения. Требуется знать структуры данных и алгоритмы.

Comment: @MaxU любыми, которые не предполагают форматирования списка какой-то функцией. По индексу обращаться можно. Здесь нужно понимать, что у вас нет каких-то особых инструментов, допустим требуется написать код не в python, а в с++.

Comment: @АндрейХрамцов, в C/C++ можно динамически выделить память под строку, увеличить размер строки на один элемент, увеличив размер выделенной памяти. В Python все это скрыто от пользователя, поэтому придется пользоваться другими структурами - например использовать связный список, как посоветовал `becouse`

Comment: В любом случае если хотите решить данную задачу (с указанными ограничениями) на Python, то придется либо воспользоваться любой функцией / методом для добавления элемента к списку (`append`, `extend`) либо создать новый результирующий список (что противоречит наложенным ограничениям). Другого варианта я не вижу...

Comment: @MaxU если в питоне нельзя как-то выделять память или работать с ней, то задачу действительно не решить, не пользуясь этими функциями.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ins(lst, index, value):
  save=value
  for x in range(index, len(lst)): 
    if x==index:
      save,lst[index] = lst[index],value
    else :
      save,lst[x] = lst[x],save 
  return lst+[save]

lst = [1,2,3]
print(ins(lst,0,5))
lst = [1,2,3]
print(ins(lst,2,5))
lst = [1,2,3]
print(ins(lst,3,5))

[5, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 5, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: `lst+[save]` - неявно создаст новый список ;)

Comment: иначе я не понимаю совсем откуда он возьмется :(

Comment: по-моему задача нерешаемая если нельзя использовать функции для работы со списками (такие как `.apend()` или `.extend()`) и при этом нельзя создавать новые списки...

Comment: @MaxU, у меня, кстати вопрос к вам есть. Не знаю, стоит создавать его как официальный вопрос :) я пытался в панде сравнить две колонки с третьей и у меня получилось вот только таким длинным путем `[['Средний','Высокий']].gt(df1['Значение'].values.reshape(-1,1)).sum(axis=1)` Если я чего-то не знаю, то давайте может задам вопрос, а если так и должно быть, то фиг с ним. вот тут ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1050433/180637

Comment: @splash58 спасибо за решение. Не уверен создаётся ли новый список, но вы пользуетесь конкатенацией на `return` результата.

Comment: Да, но я разделяю мнение @MaxU чуть выше в комментариях про неочевидную решаемость при таких ограничениях

Comment: @splash58, думаю стоит задать новый вопрос...

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо! Тогда завтра, пошел спать :)